# Wordpress - menu logged in/logged out

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up my website so that when nobody's logged in, the 'logged-in' menu shows up, and when someone's logged in, it switches to the 'logged-out' menu. So, I made these two menus, and I found this code that's supposed to make it all work:

```php
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
    } else { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    } 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

But here's the issue: it's changing both the 'main menu' and the 'secondary menu'. I only want the 'secondary menu' to change. The 'logged-in' menu is showing up in both places (the 'logged-out' one works fine though).

Since I can only assign one menu to the 'secondary menu' slot, I'm kind of stuck on how to fix this. If anyone knows how to tweak this code so it does what I want, I'd be super grateful for the help!

Comment: `$args` is an array of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments, so it should contain a `menu` entry as well.

Comment: function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    if ( isset( $args['menu'] ) && $args['menu'] === 'Sekundär-Menü' ) {
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
            $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
        } else { 
            $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );

I also tried this without any luck

Comment: Don't know how this menu is embedded in your template - it might not use the menu name in that place, but the slug instead, or a menu id.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I utilized the "echo" command to showcase the theme location, which allowed me to obtain the accurate name of the secondary menu.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    // Überprüfe, ob die theme_location auf 'secondary' gesetzt ist
    if ( isset( $args['theme_location'] ) && 'top-bar' === $args['theme_location'] ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
            $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
        } else { 
            $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
        }
    } 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```